# (MU2) Direct messaging library or provider

Tags: library, java, email, python, saas

I'm looking for a library or even a SaaS provider for [Direct](http://wiki.directproject.org/) [<sup>1</sup>] messaging, a requirement for [Meaningful Use phase 2 certification](http://www.healthit.gov/providers-professionals/step-5-achieve-meaningful-use-stage-2).

I prefer tools with a REST API or alternatively Python or Java.

[<sup>1</sup>] Direct is a project for health care institutions to improve their communication with patients etc.

Comment: Hi, did you come around this? Found anything?

Comment: @AngeloFuchs Actually ended out rolling our own library (using OpenSSL for doing the actual encryption bits). Depending on your needs it may not be that prohibitive to actually just roll your own (using Python, that is).

Comment: I see, if you ever publish your library be sure to leave a note.